# XAMPP on Flashdrive cannot start Apache, MySQL on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-7, xampp

XAMPP is unable to start Apache or MySQL on a windows 7 system when run from a flashdrive.

The control panel indicates that the server is starting, but it never actually comes online. Additionally, the control panel process refuses to end; Task Manager end tasking is required to make it stop.

Is there a specialized setting either in XAMPP or Windows that needs to be made to achieve operation? Is there a version incompatibility? Anyone know a way to get this running?

Comment: You cannot use Services on Flashdrive. It was already mentioned in the installation of XAMPP 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [XAMPP Lite](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646) -- it has all of the main features of XAMPP, and runs flawlessly from a flash drive.

Be sure to select "no drive letters" during the setup process to maintain portability.